# How to print from a browser in an android device

Tags: printing

So, here is the situation: We are a SaaS company, our contractor haves multiple Zebra phones and Zebra printers, they want their salesman to be able to go to the place where they sell their stuff (they are product providers), and make an invoice in their phone, then print it and give it to the person in charge of the place.

I want to be able to print the invoice from the browser (since our software is a web app), the printer is attached to the android device with Bluetooth, there can't be any dependence to computers (so I guess I can't use Google Cloud Print) and it shouldn't be a long process, it should be efficient.

I also can't pay for printing apps, I downloaded lots of them and either they don't work, or they ask you to pay after certain amount of prints, if it's needed, we can develop an application to connect the printer with the browser.

Printer: Zebra iMZ320.
Android version: 7.1.2 (Nougat).
The browser they use will be variable, we can't develop something just for certain browser, it must print from ANY modern browser.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bluetooth printing isn't something native to Android, in this case Bluetooth is used only to "help" your device connect to the printer via the network or WiFi Direct... I suggest you contact Zebra to see if they have Android printing support.

Comment: Zebra does have [its own printer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zebra.android.zebrautilities), though it seems they've abandoned it (no updates for 3 years) – or replaced it [by this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zebra.kdu). Have you tried one of them?